# Pivot or Formula for Reverse Lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I am creating a list of features and the audiences that will be targeted for those features. Each stakeholder group (audience) is separate by a comma in the list. Now, if I want to create a pivot or some formula to see which features are applicable for a particular stakeholder group, then how would I do that.

[image: sample table]

In the image above, the table has the features listed vertically, and each feature has a list of SGs (stakeholder groups) assigned to it. Now, I want another table in where I can select any particular SG, and it will return the features this SG is mapped against. Here is the expected outcome:

[image: Sample output]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Since SGs are duplicate therefor will return multiple Features, this is what you are suppose to do or anything else,, better edit the post and attach expected output also !!

Comment: @RajeshS I added sample output

Comment: If you have a reasonable number of features and SGs, and you don't NEED the output of the vertical feature list to roll up without interstitial blanks, `=IF(ISERROR(FIND(D$1,$B2)),"",$A2)` copied from the first cell under SG1 across the entire sample output table will work (assuming **SG1** is in `D1`)

Comment: @JayD,, now check the post I've solved the issue!!

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem can be solved by using few Helper Columns:**

[image]

**How it works:**

Enter header `SG1, SG2, SG3 & SG4` in Cell `D95, E95, F95 & G95` also in `I95, J95, K95 & in L95`.

- Enter this Formula in Cell `D96` and fill it 
  Down then Right.

  `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D$95, $C96)), D$95, "")`
- You get **Helper Values** in Range `D96:G102`.
- Enter this Array (CSE) Formula in Cell `I96`, 
  finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, fill it 
  Down then Right.

  `{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$96:$A$102,SMALL(IF(D$96:D$102=I$95,ROW($A$96:$A$102)-MIN(ROW($A$96:$A$102))+1),ROWS($I$95:I95))),"")}`
- You get **expected output** in Range 
  `I96:L102`.

*Adjust Cell references in the formula as needed.*